# Know which keywords google has associated to my website

Tags: seo, keywords, seo-audit

I recently opened my website.
I know it has been crawled by google bot (from the search console and the "site:www.example.com").

**NOTE** : this is not a blog but an app where users login. Their data is kept private. So, content is not meant to change or getting big. But my competitors have the same constraints.

However, I would like to know which keywords google has associated with my website.

On Google Ads, in the "Tools" > "Find new keywords" menu, if I search for a competitor domain, it shows keywords associated with the relevant field. But with mine, It returns an empty list!
Anyway, my competitor have a name that is not less or more in the field as me.
**Is this a relevant way to check which keywords are associated with a domain?**

Right now, I'm writing more content but I'd like to be able to check the incidence of it. Did google catch up with those keywords?

I tried Ubersuggest and submitted my domain : organic keywords is empty!
How can it be?

My keywords are in `<h[123]>` tags, meta description, meta keywords... The site rank technically ok in Google Page Speed Insight : it's fast, got https, is mobile friendly, etc.

**Of course, I'm not expecting to rank Number 1 in two weeks, but - at least - my webapp should be associated with the right keywords!**

**-- EDIT 2019/07/23--**

My site is a Vuejs SPA page. Basically, it means it's not rendered on the server but with javascript on the client browser.
I noticed in the Google Search Console URL inspector that a javascript error occurred, so my page was seen as a blank page by Google.

NOTE : despite Google announce that their Bot started to use the very last Chrome engine in May (supporting es6), I have great doubt about it....

The tooling around Vuejs Vu-Cli3 has some quirks about polyfill/transpiling javascript es6  to es5. Basically, it would transform your code from es6 to es5, but not - by default - the dependencies :-( ...

I fixed it on 2019/07/20 and now, the page successfully draws on Google Search Console URL inspector. If you use an SPA Vuejs app, check this!

**I asked Google to make a new pass. But 3 days after no change in regard of keyword detection...**

I have done some homework about keywords and added a page of 1220 words of original content where my keywords appear regularly.

Right now, I'm not looking to rank high. I know it's a long task and would need social media activities and even bidding on keywords with Google Adds.
But, at least, Google should pick up some of my keywords!

Comment: Domain is 6 months old, and practically has no content, apart from that one page. There's one backlink to it, with a weird anchor text - "V".
Your html lang is set to "en" while in fact, it's french.
There are no shares of your page on social networks, in fact you do not have social networks connected to it.
Honestly, I doubt that this is enough for any search engine to understand what's it all about.
Suggestions: keep the heading hierarchy in tact, there's no reason for skipping h3, h4 and using h5;
Add structured data in JSON/LD format (more on schema.org about it), might help.

Comment: @mnea Thanks for your advice. I fixed the most obvious and technical elements (language!!! and tags.) I checked the V backlink : it's a kind of a dns indexer. Nothing I can do with it, I guess. There is a content page you did not see :) . But, do you think the steps I used to check associated keywords with my site (ubersuggest, google ads,) are enough? Should I improve my SEO and check regularly with those? Or do you know a better way to check a website associated keywords?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't bother trying so hard to make SEs associate your website with the topic. I think it will come naturally, as soon as you show "signs of life" - add content (If i missed the page with content, I guess it's not indexed, than that is an issue as well).
I mean, even adding meta = keywords means nothing to Google (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK7IPbnmvVU - matt cutts video). 
In the end, you have created this website for the users, not the search engines, correct? So, as soon as you get it through to people, sooner will SEs realise what your story is all about.

Comment: Thanks again! Well, about content : this is not a blog, more a web application. My users' data are kept private in their account. So, user activity might not change my website content. Competitors have the same constraints. But, indeed they have social media activity. I'll work in this direction. But, I still think keywords are important. How would someone typing those on google land on my site if google does not show it? Despite meta keywords, keywords on my page should be parsed somehow?

Comment: If it were that simple, it would be too easy :) Keywords, meta data, structured data, all of that combined is not enough for google to start showing you organically. You know why? Because there's who knows how many ppl with the same product as yours. And after all, if you show up one day on page 15 of google search, what's it to you? It's worth nothing.
You need to make some proper marketing strategy, how to promote your product. Social media promotion, paid advertising (Google ads, Linkedin ads, FB ads) guest posts, outreach to some influencers, and all that jazz.

Answer (score 2):

look at Google Search Console to see what search terms you are getting impressions & clicks for.

Just having a keyword in the page title and H1 doesn't mean Google are going to think you are worth ranking for those terms or are necessarily relevant to them. There are tons of ranking factors and especially for a young site only months old, odds are their isn't enough data on / about your site to show highly relevant stuff. Google and other tools all require a minimum amount of data to make statistically significant insights in areas like this.

I would suggest doing keyword research to find valuable terms that you know are relevant to your business and start producing content around those terms. Build up your site's authority through back link acquisition and promote it on social media.

It can take a long time to rank well for high value terms especially for newcomers to the game.

You need to add a lot of content, high quality content that is keyword targeted and supported by back links as well as being promoted socially. This could take many months, depending on your resources, before you start seeing relevant terms suggested for your site.

I would also suggest performing a full competitor analysis, looking specifically for the following things:
- What keywords do they target
- How much content do they have (on the site as a whole, on each keyword, theme or topic)
- Compare back link profiles
- Domain age
Use these data as a benchmarks for your site, you can use this to see what it takes to rank for keywords.

Comment: Has that answered your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alec. I edited my question because I had technical issues which prevented Google Bot to parse my page. Actually I think it parsed a white page or something like "Please enable JavaScript". Now, it's fixed & the bot performed a new pass. I know I'm not going to perform a high rank. But, I'm still worrying that basically my app is associated with NO keywords at all!

Comment: If you've resolved technical issues and the site is able to rank for target keywords, maybe your focus of what is sees as similar is too strong at this stage.